# Ajax won't catch Pusher real time event

Tags: php, html, ajax, real-time, pusher

I have made a Pusher messaging demo system based of a book a read. I created 3 files, test.html,test.js,post.php. When I click submit, ajax does not catch it and stop it from refreshing.
I check the Pusher log, and the php message was sent with the values. I am lead to believe the error was in test.js. Below are the codes.

Test.js

```
(function($){


var pusher= new pusher('bab47e76c61c0af0818a'),
    channel = pusher.subscribe('exercise-3-2);

channel
   .bind(
'send-message', function( data ) {
var cont= $('#messages');

cont.find('.no-messages').remove();


$('<li>')
    .html(data.msg)
.appendTo(cont);
}
);




$('form').submit(function(){
$.post('post.php', $(this).serialize());

$('#message').val('').focus();

return false;

});


})(jQuery);
```

post.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'Pusher.php';

$key = 'bab47e76c61c0af0818a';
$secret = 'PRIVATEINFO';
$app_id = 'PRIVATEINFO';

$pusher=new Pusher($key, $secret, $app_id);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']))
{
$data =array(
    'name'=> htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['name'])),
     'msg'=> htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['message'])),
  );

$pusher->trigger('exercise-3-2', 'send-message', $data);
}
```

and test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test!</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
Testing Pusher!
</header>

<section>
<form method="post" action="post.php">
<label>
NAME:
<input type="text" name="name" 
placeholder="i.e. John" />
</label>
<label>
Message:
<input type="text" name="message" 
id="message" value="Hey!" />
</label>
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
</section>
<aside>
<h2> Messages!</h2>
<ul id="messages">
<li class="no-messages"> no messages yet</li>
</ul>
</aside>
<script src="http://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>

<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will most likely have a better response if you include formatting in the above code, since there's a significant amount of it.  I'd suggest using [this for HTML/JS](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and [this for PHP.](http://beta.phpformatter.com/)

Comment: As a side note, it looks like you are overwriting the `pusher` variable in your JavaScript.  The `$.ajax()` call also doesn't have a `.success()` or `.fail()` callback, so you'll never catch the response from PHP.  [Might check this article out to get the data back from your AJAX call.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: Hmm. I put it into the format link. But I keep getting not formatted as code when I try to post